# Can I reload selector data from server without page refresh in jquery?

Tags: jquery

I want to refresh one element on page, load element html from server, but I don't want to refresh all page and reload it. Can I do that? I think, that load function will be good for it, but mat be you can advice me something more good way?

Comment: You can either use the load method or just populate the element with new content, probably after clear it, via ajax in the succes block. Not mistery here. It's done all the time.

Comment: Are you trying to update one div or element ont he page after an AJAX request?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to load data from server without refreshing the page using `jQuery Ajax` and yes `load` is one method among many; for example, if you want to load some data on click event of a button then you may simply use something loke this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#button_id').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // Required if clicked element is a link
        $( "#result_Div" ).load( "some_page.html");
    });
});
```

Check more on [jQuery website](http://api.jquery.com/load/). Also check [get/ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) method which is something like this:

```
//...
$.get('some_page.html', function(response) {
    $('#result_div').html(response);
});
```